# How to define how many queries go to database for an anction?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, logging, nhibernate

I have legacy asp.net mvc project with controllers which return views and some web api controllers. The database is ms sql. ORM is NHibernate.
I want to log how many queries go into the database for an action.
Somethinq like this

```
{namepage}, {controller}, {action} - {count of queries}
```

I think it can be achieved via a global filter. 
Could you give me ideas about how I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

One possible [option](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2008/10/26/exploring-nhibernate-statistics-part-1-simple-data-fetching.html) is with the statistics provided by the `SessionFactory`. The issue here might be that the `SessionFactory` typically lives for the lifetime of the process, so I'm not sure how you would isolate the stats for that action only.

There's also the concept of [interceptors](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html) that you could explore. IIRC, there's a method you can implement related to query prep/execution.

Comment: There is also the concept of event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to be able to do it from an action filter.  The filter doesn't really know what's going inside the controller method.

Adding to what David said, I think an interceptor is probably the way to go.  There's a nice implementation of an Interceptor [here](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html)

And here's a copy of the implementation since people get mad with links

```
using System;       
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Type;

public class AuditInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor {

    private int updates;
    private int creates;
    private int loads;

    public override void OnDelete(object entity,
                                  object id,
                                  object[] state,
                                  string[] propertyNames,
                                  IType[] types)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    public override bool OnFlushDirty(object entity, 
                                      object id, 
                                      object[] currentState,
                                      object[] previousState,
                                      string[] propertyNames,
                                      IType[] types)
    {
        if ( entity is IAuditable ) {
            updates++;
            for ( int i=0; i < propertyNames.Length; i++ ) {
                if ( "lastUpdateTimestamp".Equals( propertyNames[i] ) ) {
                    currentState[i] = new DateTime();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool OnLoad(object entity, 
                                object id, 
                                object[] state,
                                string[] propertyNames,
                                IType[] types)
    {
        if ( entity is IAuditable ) {
            loads++;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override bool OnSave(object entity, 
                                object id, 
                                object[] state,
                                string[] propertyNames,
                                IType[] types)
    {
        if ( entity is IAuditable ) {
            creates++;
            for ( int i=0; i<propertyNames.Length; i++ ) {
                if ( "createTimestamp".Equals( propertyNames[i] ) ) {
                    state[i] = new DateTime();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override void AfterTransactionCompletion(ITransaction tx)
    {
        if ( tx.WasCommitted ) {
            System.Console.WriteLine(
                "Creations: " + creates +
                ", Updates: " + updates +
                ", Loads: " + loads);
        }
        updates=0;
        creates=0;
        loads=0;
    }

}
```

you could replace the method bodies with something that reads the StackTrace, but you can get the Controller call using

```
var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
            var method =
                stackTrace.GetFrames()
                    .Select(f => f.GetMethod())
                    .Where(
                        m =>
                            m.IsPublic && m.DeclaringType != null &&
                            m.DeclaringType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Controller)))
                    .Select(m => new {Method = m.Name, Controller = m.DeclaringType.Name}).ToList();
```

Modify this query for ApiControllers.

Then collate all the data in the AfterTransactionCompletion assuming you are using an NHibernate transaction and you are opening it in your BeginRequest and closing it in EndRequest.